# How to retrieve column values into another tableview in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am very beginner to IOS,I have deposit table and expense table in my database I want to retrieve only deposit amount from deposit table and expense amount from expense table into two tableviews means one is for deposit amount tableview and another one is for expense amount tableview in single screen. the below is my dbmodelclass.h in this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>
@interface dbModelClass : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableDictionary *readDic;
    NSMutableArray *readArray;
}
+(NSString *)connectDb;
+(BOOL)createTable;
+(BOOL)createTable3;
+(int)saveData:(NSMutableArray *)data;
+(int)saveData2:(NSMutableArray *)data;
+(NSMutableArray *)getData;
@end
```

this is my `dbmodelclass.m`

```
#import "dbModelClass.h"
#import "Expences.h"
@implementation dbModelClass;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self)
   {
      // Custom initialization
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

   // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
+(NSString *)connectDb
{
   NSArray *docDir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,          NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *dbFolder=[docDir objectAtIndex:0];
   NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
   if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:dbFolder])
   {
       [manager createDirectoryAtPath:dbFolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
   }
   NSString *dbPath=[dbFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fappDB.sqlite"];
   if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath])
   {
       [manager copyItemAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fappDB.sqlite"] toPath:dbPath  error:nil];
   }
   NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);
   return dbPath;
}

+(BOOL)createTable
{
   NSString *dbpath=[dbModelClass connectDb];
   sqlite3 *dbObj;
   if (sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
   {
      sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
      const char *sql="create table deposit(deposit_amount VARCHAR,remarks VARCHAR)";
      sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
      if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
      {
          NSLog(@"tabel created successfull");
      }
      else
      {
         NSLog(@"tabel already created");
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
      sqlite3_close(dbObj);
   }   
   return YES;
} 
+(BOOL)createTable3;
{
   NSString *dbpath=[dbModelClass connectDb];
   sqlite3 *dbObj;
   if (sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
   {
       sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
       const char *sql="create table expense2(expense_title VARCHAR,description VARCHAR,amount VARCHAR,paidcash VARCHAR,date VARCHAR,remarks VARCHAR)";
       sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
       if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
       {
           NSLog(@"tabel created successfull");
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@"tabel already created");
       }
       sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
       sqlite3_close(dbObj);
    }
    return YES;
}

+(int)saveData:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
sqlite3 *dbObj;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
NSString *dbPath=[dbModelClass connectDb];
const char *sql=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into deposit(deposit_amount,remarks) values(\"%@\",\"%@\")",[data objectAtIndex:0],[data objectAtIndex:1]]UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[data objectAtIndex:0]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[data objectAtIndex:1]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
      NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt executed properly");
       }
       else
          NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt not executed");

          sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
           sqlite3_close(dbObj);

  }
return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(dbObj);
} 

+(int)saveData2:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
sqlite3 *dbObj;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
NSString *dbPath=[dbModelClass connectDb];
const char *sql=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into expense2(expense_title,description,amount,paidcash,date,remarks) values(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",[data objectAtIndex:0],[data objectAtIndex:1],[data objectAtIndex:2],[data objectAtIndex:3],[data objectAtIndex:4],[data objectAtIndex:5]]UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dbObj)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[data objectAtIndex:0]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[data objectAtIndex:1]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [[data objectAtIndex:2]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [[data objectAtIndex:3]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [[data objectAtIndex:4]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [[data objectAtIndex:5]UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbObj, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt executed properly");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"data insertion stmnt not executed");

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(dbObj);

 }
return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(dbObj);
}
-(NSMutableArray *)getData
{
sqlite3 *dbobj;
NSString *dbpath  =[dbModelClass connectDb];
readArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbobj)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;

    //**** NSString *string=@"SELECT name FROM emptable";
    NSString *string=@"SELECT *FROM deposit WHERE deposit_amount";
    const char *query=[string UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbobj, query, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
    readDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] forKey:@"deposit_amount"];
            // NSString *aName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            // NSString *pwd=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            //[readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"remarks"];
            //  [readArray addObject:aName];
            // [readArray1 addObject:pwd];
            [readArray addObject:readDic];
            // NSLog(@"%@",readDic);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
NSLog(@"%@",readArray);
sqlite3_close(dbobj);
return readArray;
}



 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

This is my `netviewcontroller.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NetViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>//DepositTable *depositCo
{
IBOutlet  UILabel *depositLabel,*expenseLabel,*netvalueLabel;
IBOutlet  UITextField *netvalueText;
IBOutlet UITableView *depositTable,*expenseTable;


}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UILabel  *depositLabel,*expenseLabel,*netvalueLabel;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITextField *netvalueText;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITableView *depositTable,*expenseTable;



-(IBAction)netvalue:(id)sender;

@end
```

This my `netviewcontroller.m`

```
#import "NetViewController.h"
#import "dbModelClass.h"
@interface NetViewController ()

@end

@implementation NetViewController
@synthesize depositLabel,expenseLabel,netvalueLabel,depositTable,expenseTable,netvalueText;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[dbModelClass connectDb];
[dbModelClass getData];
NSMutableArray *issuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  [dbModelClass financeappDB:@"SELECT * FROM  deposit" resultsArray:issuesArray];
NSLog(@"contents count:%d",[issuesArray count]);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)netvalue:(id)sender
{

}
@end
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing things good :).

1. Why you ar creating an object witch inherits from a `UIViewController` to manager the DataBase, you can just create an object that inherits from `NSObject`.
2. In the getData methode you are asking the data just for the deposit table, you should pass  parameters ( table name and amount) to your methode to know if you want data from deposit table or expense2 table.
3. And finally in the NetViewController class you can do :

...

```
[dbModelClass connectDb];
NSArray *depositData =  [dbModelClass getDataWith....]; // here you fetch your database with deposit table and others param 

NSArray * expenseData = [dbModelClass getDataWith....]; // Here you fetch your database with expensive table and others param
```

Edited answer :

You can do like this for example :

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getDataForTable:(NSString *)tableName withAmount:(NSString *)amountName
{
sqlite3 *dbobj;
NSString *dbpath  =[dbModelClass connectDb];
readArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String], &dbobj)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;

    //**** NSString *string=@"SELECT name FROM emptable";

   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT *FROM %@ WHERE %@",tableName,amountName];

   const char *query=[string UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbobj, query, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
    readDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            [readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] forKey:@"deposit_amount"];
            // NSString *aName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            // NSString *pwd=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            //[readDic setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"remarks"];
            //  [readArray addObject:aName];
            // [readArray1 addObject:pwd];
            [readArray addObject:readDic];
            // NSLog(@"%@",readDic);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Add this
`-(NSMutableArray *)getDataForTable:(NSString *)tableName withAmount:(NSString *)amountName` in the `dbModelClass.h`

and now you can call this methode in NetViewController by passing it the table name and the amount :

```
[dbModelClass connectDb];
NSArray * depositResult = [dbModelClass getDataWith:@"deposite" amountName:@"deposit_amount"];
```

// Do same thing for the other table by passing it the appropriate names.

PS : this code is not tested and you should refactor it, it's just to show you how to pass parameters for a methode

Comment: Actually I am very new to this one please can you explain me brifely

Comment: while we were done the above procedure "No known class method for selector getDatawith:deposit_amount" exception was occuring Here deposit_amount is amountName

Comment: Add the methode in the dbModelClass.h : -(NSMutableArray *)getDataForTable:(NSString *)tableName withAmount:(NSString *)amountName

Comment: Yes am added but it's coming Please SamirJi help me

Comment: Putt the methode as a Class methode by replacing the "-" with the "+", in dbModelClass.h and dbModelClass.m

Comment: +(NSMutableArray *)getDataForTable:(NSString *)tableName withAmount:(NSString *)amountName; // in dbModelClass.h and  and +(NSMutableArray *)getDataForTable:(NSString *)tableName withAmount:(NSString *)amountName { ....}; // in dbModelClass.m

Comment: Yes I did but same error was coming ,,Is any method declaration in NetviewController.h

Comment: post the new code of the dbModelClass.f and dbModelClass.m where you have added the methode +(NSMutableArray *)getDataForTable....

Comment: dbmodelclass.h    Add the methode in the dbModelClass.h : -(NSMutableArray *)getDataForTable:(NSString *)tableName withAmount:(NSString *)amountName – samir 1 min ago
And dbmodelclass.m

Comment: I am sorry, i can't help you more. You should look at the documentation how to define a methode ( instance/class methode methode). or if you want you can share with me your project and i will see what happen  but Please you should read the Apple documentation about Objective C programming.

Comment: Doesn't helpfull but your suggested read the Apple documentation it's fine

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to your question.

The best solution is actually the easiest.

Master viewController with two embedded tableViewControllers, each presenting and managing one table from your database.

During viewDidLoad, you will create an instance of each tableViewController, set it's frame to locate on the desired coordinates of your master view and add it to the master view.

Now you can have a clean and simple delegate model for each table and if you keep the instance of each tableViewController available within the master view controller (allocate as properties), you will be able to communicate to each table from the master view.

The more complicated way is to add two tableView to the master view xib, wire them both up to the datasource and delegate methods in the master viewController and then test each call to the delegate methods to determine which tableView called the method.  I've done it but it's a pain to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Please can you explain me step by step then only I will understand I am very new to this one